# How to implement ajax in node.js to achieve partial postback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, npm

I am using [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) (express framework and hbs engine) and [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) to develop an application.

I want to implement an ajax call to  to page for partial post back.

Comment: what do you mean by "ajax call to to page" ?

Comment: i have 2 select box.. on elect of one selectbox value i want to populate other selectBox. and i do not want to refresh hole page. so i want to do partial postback... plz suggest how to achive it in code level using node.js

Comment: This has been answered in several ways. Just add a `route` for your API and return a JSON response. You don't need socket.io. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289276/nodejs-express-ajax-posting-w-jquery-and-recieving-response

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317219/ajax-to-refresh-a-partial-view-using-express-and-jquery?rq=1

Comment: i am using hbs as engine... plz suggest based on that...

Comment: i m able to add Ajax now and getting the filter data. but my problem is that i m not able to  render it in my html page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**>**pass ur URL,and parameter to this function:It is working fine....****

function ajaxRequest(url, succesCallBck, completeCallBck, errorCallBck)
    {
 $.ajax({
     url: url,
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
complete: completeCallBck,
success: succesCallBck,
error: errorCallBck
  });
}

Comment: create your sever code function and pass url with parameter... it will give a partial rander to your code

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others in comments, the best approach for this is described in [Ajax to refresh a partial view using express and JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317219/ajax-to-refresh-a-partial-view-using-express-and-jquery?rq=1)